# Dimensionality-reduction by specific methods

Tags: dimensionality-reduction

I'm working  on feature extraction of facial image using local binary pattern. How to reduce the dimensions of my feature vector?which method should I use for feature reduction?

Answer (score 0):

Check out SVD decomposition. Practically, it replaces matrix M with the new matrix Mk with a lower rank.

For example

```
import numpy as np
U, S, V = np.linalg.svd(lena_image)
```

Here Mk is a dot product of these matrices.

You can consider it like a compression which preserves only the most important information (extracting features)

Comment: thanks a lot. but I'm using matlab and I already have the feature vector which length is 65536. now I want to reduce the dimension.